# Stripe JS files not being loaded due to Content-Policy in React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

I am using stripe payment intents api to handle payments in my app. For the backend I am using ExpressJS and for the frontend I am using React (craco) with stripe elements. However, I am facing this error:

```
VM148:1 Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src https://m.stripe.network 'sha256-/5Guo2nzv5n/w6ukZpOBZOtTJBJPSkJ6mhHpnBgm3Ls='".
```

eventhough I didn't set any CSPs for my app.

Comment: Did you consider addressing what the error message is telling you the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out one of my chrome extensions was blocking stripe js files which caused this error, after disabling the extension it started working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Can you paste the relevant code and show me how you integrate Stripe?